# PHPUnit: Mocking __get() results in "__get() must take exactly 1 argument ..."

Tags: php, phpunit, overloading, built-in

I've got a problem with mocking an overloaded __get($index) method.
The code for the class to be mocked and the system under test that consumes it is as follows:

```
<?php
class ToBeMocked
{
    protected $vars = array();

    public function __get($index)
    {
        if (isset($this->vars[$index])) {
            return $this->vars[$index];
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}

class SUTclass
{
    protected $mocky;

    public function __construct(ToBeMocked $mocky)
    {
        $this->mocky = $mocky;
    }

    public function getSnack()
    {
        return $this->mocky->snack;
    }
}
```

Test looks as follows:

```
<?php    
class GetSnackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $stub;
    protected $sut;

    public function setUp()
    {
       $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('ToBeMocked')
                     ->setMethods(array('__get')
                     ->getMock();

       $sut = new SUTclass($mock);
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function shouldReturnSnickers()
    {
        $this->mock->expects($this->once())
                   ->method('__get')
                   ->will($this->returnValue('snickers');

        $this->assertEquals('snickers', $this->sut->getSnack());
    }
}
```

Real code is a little bit more complex, though not much, having "getSnacks()" in its parent class. But this example should suffice.

Problem is I get the following error, when executing the test with PHPUnit:

```
Fatal error: Method Mock_ToBeMocked_12345672f::__get() must take exactly 1 argument in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php(231)
```

When I debug I can't even reach the test method. It seems it breaks at setting up the mock object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, I tested a little bit further. Problem really seems to be at construction of the mocked class.
If I create it with ->setMethods(array('blabla')) he gets to the test methods. If I use ->setMethods(array('__get')) he breaks.

Comment: You're right - the problem is something to do with how PHP mock objects is generating the mock - none of the answer's below address this. I'm getting this problem in PHPUnit 4.0 - what version are you using?

Comment: I've tried to recreate this with different combinations of versions of PHPUnit and it's Mock Object dependency from the latest version available (4.8.2 at time of writing) back to PHPUnit 3.5, and cannot get it to break in this way using my environment - PHP 5.5 on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS. Unless the original poster can expand on this question by remembering the combination of versions they were using, I would recommend this question is closed.

Comment: Phiu, coming back to this question after 3 years via google. :D 

In earlier times it was PHP 5.3 and PHPUnit 3.6.x or 3.7.x I think. Didn't get the error for a long time. Now I get it again using PHP 5.5 / PHPUnit 4.8.26.

I think it's a problem of the combination of all our unit tests somehow crossfeeding s**t amongst each other. Cause going back to 3.7.38 I get different errors.

I'll try my best to localize the problem some more. Maybe it's just some stinky tests from good ol' times. :D

Answer (score 2):

`__get()` takes an argument, so you need to provide the mock with one:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function shouldReturnSnickers()
{
    $this->mock->expects($this->once())
               ->method('__get')
               ->with($this->equalTo('snack'))
               ->will($this->returnValue('snickers'));

    $this->assertEquals('snickers', $this->sut->getSnack());
}
```

The `with()` method sets the argument for the mocked method in PHPUnit. You can find more details in the section on [Test Doubles](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html).

Comment: The inclusion of the `with()` call is what I expected to fix this, but it doesn't for me (PHPUnit 4.4). Did you *test* this answer before giving it? Just wondering if you are simply regurgitating the docs, or know this to work?

Comment: I think I was using 3.7 at the time. This (or something like it) worked, but I can't find what I was referencing when I wrote this.

But no, I tested this code.

Comment: Cheers. I must be doing something daft (am a bit of a PHP newbie)

Comment: FWIW, I couldn't get it working on 4.4 after you commented, so it's possible this doesn't work on the new version or I copied something wrong (looks like I was missing a closing parens at least). So who knows. I stopped using the `__get` in the project I pulled this from.

Comment: Cheers for the clarification mate.

Comment: I was also having trouble using with(), it was just not working. I was able to use this `$planMock->method('__get')->willReturnCallback(function ($propertyName) { // switch $propertyName and return value });` to successfully return the correct response for each magic method

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hidden in the comments, but @dfmuir's answer put me on the right track. Mocking a `__get` method is straight forward if you use a callback.

```
$mock
    ->method('__get')
    ->willReturnCallback(function ($propertyName) {
        switch($propertyName) {
            case 'id':
                return 123123123123;
            case 'name':
                return 'Bob';
            case 'email':
                return 'bob@bob.com';
        }
    }
);

$this->assertEquals('bob@bob.com', $mock->email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the mocked magic method __get. Probably you call there one more __get method from another and not properly mocked object.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in the `setUp` method of your `GetSnackTest` class is incorrect.
If you want the code of the `__get` method to be executed (which would be the point of your test> I suppose), you have to change the way you call `setMethods` in the `setup` method.
[Here's the complete explanation](https://jtreminio.com/blog/unit-testing-tutorial-part-v-mock-methods-and-overriding-constructors/#the-four-pathways-of-getmockbuilder), but here's the relevant part:

> Passing an array containing method names
>
> The methods you have identified:
>
> Are all stubs,
>   All return null by default,
>   Are easily overridable

So, you need to call `setMethods` by passing `null`, or by passing an array that contains *some* methods (the ones that you *really* want to stub), but *not-* `__get` (because you actually want the code of that method to be executed).

The, in the `shouldReturnSnickers` method, you will simply want to want to call `$this->assertEquals('snickers', $this->sut->getSnack());`, without the preceding lines with the `expect` part.
This will ensure the code of your `__get` method is actually executed and tested.

Answer (score -2):

withAnyParameters() method can help you, this works correct:

```
$this->mock -> expects($this -> once())  
    -> method('__get') -> withAnyParameters()
    -> will($this -> returnValue('snikers'));
```